# I am attempting to use twilioPhoneVerify to sendSmsCode to ("1+##########") I get a return status code of 400 and message Invalid Parameter

Tags: twilio

This is a flutter project using Andriod Studio.
here is the code.

```dart
await _twilioPhoneVerify!.sendSmsCode(phoneNumberController.text.trim());
```

I have tried formatting the phone number in many ways always with the same response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This package](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_phone_verify) (which it looks like you are using) is **not a secure** way to use the Twilio API and I **recommend against using it**.

The package requires you to store your account credentials within the source code of the application, which means a malicious user could decompile your application, extract your credentials and use them to abuse your Twilio account and cost you a lot of money.

Instead, I recommend that you create your own server-side implementation of calling the [Twilio Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api) that keeps your credentials secure on the server. Then you can make requests to your server from your application without exposing your credentials.